# Comparing the content of a file using MD5 in JAVA

Tags: java, hash, md5

I am presently comparing the lsit of files using MD5sum. How to group similar kind of files into a folder using these hash values? Will the hash difference between the two files will be less?

For example: I am having a file which contains a name "HELLO" and the other pdf file contains "hello", these both are more or less same. so these files needs to be grouped. will my idea of finding hash difference help?

Or any other idea? Please help me to sort this out.

Answer (score 1):

No. The hashes will be completely different and there will be no correlation. You can use hashes if you want to divide them uniformly into different buckets, but it doesn't work with grouping similar files.

Comment: Is there a appropriate method to find file source hash

Comment: What's "file source hash"?

Comment: I meant to find the hash value for a pdf file, do we have any algorithms?

Comment: Uh... well we have MD5 that you mentioned using, SHA-1 is another one, and it should be preferred to MD5.

Comment: How this can be employed to group similar files?. can you please brief me.

Comment: Like I said, it can't. You don't seem to understand what hashing means. A good hash function will generate **completely** different hashes for a file that contains "Hello1" and a file that contains "Hello2". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function

Comment: fine.I understood now.